# Should I report an instance of nepotism - misconduct in favour of sexual partner?

Tags: ethics, sexual-misconduct

It came to my awareness a case of nepotism in my academic network.

It concerns a professor and a former female student of him. The professor and the student had relationship while she was conducting her Master thesis under his supervision. For the year she was writing her thesis, the professor intervened through an academic network he is heavily involved, to give her a scholarship although she didn't have prior outstanding performance.
For her Master thesis he proposed her for some industry prize that she obviously won.

After finishing the thesis she changed city and moved to a nearby city for her PhD (also the Prof. was married with 3 children).
Within the first 2.5 years of her Phd she hasn't produced any scientific output. The student and the professor visit several conferences abroad together in order to have time for their affair.

Now it came into my awareness that he is planning to involve her in a prestigious exchange program so that she will be able to work in his city. The plan involves a newly founded start-up and some of his collaborators/friends abroad. She will "collaborate" with the collaborators abroad, but from distance since the start-up claims to be flexible with location.
So in essence, she will appear to be working with some other Prof. abroad to get accepted into the exchange program, but she will work remotely from the city of her boyfriend professor. Also the Professor recently broke up with his wife.

Since all this is very shady, I am thinking whether someone should inform the directors/board of the exchange program.

What do you think?

Comment: I don't think the details about how the professor advocated for the student are relevant.  It's normal for professors to seek funding for their (former) students.  Having an affair with a student is unethical, but many unethical things happen.  What does this have to do with you?  And are you asking for opinions?

Comment: The only point that matters is that this story is likely detrimental to others. This said I could have written the comment by Anonymous Physicist.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist This is why I am asking the question. Do you report the unethical things that come into your awareness? Or you just leave things perpetuating. Do you leave powerful people misbehave and do as they please, because they can just get away with it or not? The issue I mention is a major misconduct according to my perception. Promoting his girlfriend through a competitive program in order to be able to see her every day, instead of promoting the rest of 20+ students he has that are all considerably more excellent than said student.

Comment: @Alchimista It is detrimental if you consider that he promotes an undeserving student in a highly competitive program instead of promoting his other students.

Comment: @user111388 Well the fact that it is common doesn't provide any excuse to perpetuate this behaviour.  Racism against black people is also common....

Comment: @ii.iii: Yes, of course. I agree.

Comment: It sounds to me like you already made up your mind.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Not really.....

Comment: Please do not "vandalize" your own post. You may edit to remove unnecessary details; this generally improves the post while also increasing anonymity. But deleting 90% of the post is [not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could go very wrong for you. If you go around and tell people what you told us here this could be considered as defamation of the professor and I wouldn't be surprised if he outright sues you.

The questions you should ask yourself:

1. Can you prove that they indeed had a sexual relationship?
2. Are the other students of the professor indeed more skilled than the student he promoted?
3. If yes, can you prove this in any legal sense or is this just your personal opinion?

Especially if you think you are one of those more skilled students I would be very careful, this can backfire horribly. Bad performance in her PhD certainly is not enough to prove 2. There are a lot of people who don't perform well in their PhD and didn't sleep with their advisor. And even if the professor and the student are a couple now, this is in no way proof that they slept with one another during the time the professor advised the student and less so proof that he promoted her for sexual and not academic reasons.

Academia is always very concerned with integrity. Is it ethical to sleep with his students and betray ones wife? Of course not. But you shouldn't just think about some academic code of conduct the professor may or may not have broken, but about the very real legal implications **you** may face. You are risking a lawsuit in pursuing this further and your personal gain is absolutely zero.

If this would be taking place in Germany, then relevant for the discussion is the following paragraph:

> [Section 186 Malicious gossip (üble Nachrede)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p1816)
>
> Whoever asserts or disseminates a fact about another person which is
> suitable for degrading that person or negatively affecting public
> opinion about that person, unless this fact can be proved to be true,
> incurs a penalty of imprisonment for a term not exceeding one year or
> a fine and, if the offence was committed publicly or by disseminating
> material (section 11 (3)), a penalty of imprisonment for a term not
> exceeding two years or a fine.

If you insist to pursue this issue, I would strongly advise you not to mention the affair. Go to the board and tell them you think there may be a conflict of interest in the award of scholarship XY. Don't accuse the student and the professor of having had an affair, you can't say this for certain. As [Buffy](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/151209/117200) points out it is highly likely that the board already knows about the issue anyways - Leave it up to them to make the conclusions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110027/discussion-on-answer-by-theoreticalminimum-should-i-report-an-instance-of-nepoti).

Answer (score 3):

Romantic relations between academics and students (specifically, in situations when academic is in the position of power related to a student) is forbidden for academic staff and may cost them job in many places. The underlying issue is academic fairness: academics are supposed to assess and promote the students based on their academic performance only. Being in personal relations with a student compromises this ability, and at a very least makes the process look unfair.

More broadly, academic teaching is a part of public service, and therefore [Ethical standards for providers of public services](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/336942/CSPL_EthicalStandards_web.pdf) should be adhered to. In the UK, the The Seven Principles of Public Life are

- Selflessness
- Integrity
- Objectivity
- Accountability
- Openness
- Honesty
- Leadership

I leave it to you to consider how many of these principles are compromised by the ongoing romantic relation which you described.

The professors' behaviour makes me doubt that academic fairness and academic standards in your Department are strongly maintained. Hence, anyone aware about this situation could doubt that all students from this Department received their degrees and prizes for their academic merits. This can compromise the value of your hard-earned degree.

Hence, I believe you have a good grounds for complaint and should consider filing it. You may want to discuss it with student union / student service representative first to identify how you can do it in the most effective but also the safest way for yourself.

Comment: And of course you should be able to prove it.

Comment: @user111388 If you use the court of law analogy (which is not fully appropriate, btw), OP is a witness, not the prosecusion. OP should honestly report things they personally have witnessed. Collecting further evidence, investigating and proving the case is not their remit.

Comment: Well I am still unsure whether I should alert people or just keep minding my own business... But this kind of behaviour really infuriates me - both considering how this prof uses his power for his own pleasure, and how this girl accepts academic benefits from him. Complete lack of integrity from both sides!

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov I often find your answers very helpful, but I think this is bad advise an puts the OP in danger of being sued. You can't just go around and claim that people have an affair or that they abused their power. The professor will certainly take legal action against OP if he does. I don't think this is worth it.

Comment: I am not referring to any court of law. I agree that OP should not go around and collect evidence. But without having any evidence, nobody will do anything (which is good!) and the professor might sue OP and bring them before a real court of law - whether or not what OP says is true. Being right without proof is not useful, the truth does not always come into light.

Comment: @user111388 I disagree. The very concept of "proof" belongs to the court of law, and standards of "proof" are different for different cases. When people witness something which they think is wrong, they should be able to discuss it with proper people / teams in the organisation, without fear of repercussion. In a fair and just society no-one should fear speaking the truth.

Comment: @DmitrySavonstyanov: But do you then believe that we live in a fair and just society? Also, what should those teams do? OP comes and tells "hey, I witnessed the prof having an affair but I have no proof" how should they act?  And people get sued all the time for slandering. At least in my society.

Comment: @user111388 That's OK, we probably live quite different lives and don't have to agree on everything. I explained my part, and it does not seem I can clarify it any further for you.

Comment: @user111388 Probably with no proof they cannot do anything, but this will at least alert them to keep a close eye on him and second guess his motives. I am sure these kind of people lack integrity in all of their actions

Comment: @user111388 Also because we live in an unfair society that doesn't mean that we have to perpetuate this kind of behaviour in eternity. If no one steps up things will continue to roll up in the same unfair way

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov: At the very least, you should state the societies in which you have experience that one can state such things without having to be feared to be sued in your answer. In many countries, this advice (just tell them even without proof) could be dangerous.

Comment: @ii.iii: Maybe yes, maybe no -- but at the very least, if someone steps up, they should think about what could happen (namely a lawsuit or a repuation for one who makes up stories about their enemies).

Comment: @user111388 I am not anonymous here - I use my real name. Anyone interested about the scope of my experience can simply use a search engine. Anonymous users, on the contrary, may want to say a few words about themselves to clarify the limits of their experience to OP.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov: I don't know what I type into a search engine that I find out for which kind of comitees you have experience on. Even if I knew for which peoples honesty you can vouch, it is still useful for a reader to have in the answer a line of  "In France& Jamaica, one can tell search comitees those things without having to fear being sued or a bad reputation". As I am not writing an answer, I dont see a need to say something about me (note that the other answerer quoted a relevant paragraph!)  All I want to do is to make you aware that your great experience might not be universal.

Comment: @user111388 You will note that in my answer I also cite a relevant (UK) documentation related to ethics of public service. Note that a paragraph on (German) laws about gossip is actually irrelevant, as OP considers reporting a potential offence to a designated officer, not to general public.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov: So please, add to the question that this answer (one may report without proof and without danger) is only about the UK (if this is the case)! I noted that the link is about UK but I thought you wanted to make an argument about the whole worls! So please add this- it is absolutely crucial to have precise answers here since the OP does not indicate their country (as far as I see).

Comment: @user111388 Ethics committees work quite similarly in most research-intensive countries, so my answer is not exclusively about UK. Note that ethics (as opposite to law) is something people agree on broadly and softly. There are of course small differences in wording and procedures in each place, but it's down to a particular ethics panel to investigate and interpret each case on its own merits. OP should only report the matter truthfully if they decide to. They don't have to be an ethics expert to proceed. All this can be explained to you or OP by your local Ethics representative, actually.

Answer (score 2):

While [TheoreticalMinimum](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/151206/75368) gives sufficient reasons not to act here, let me suggest a few more considerations before you do.

I think you are making assumptions here that aren't obviously correct and might be quite wrong.

You seem to assume that the professor is predatory. I don't know if that is true or not and there is no place in academia for predators, but it might be something more personal and private. Has he shown such behavior in the past? You may also be assuming that the student is, in her own way, using her body, rather than her mind, to advance her career. I doubt you have evidence of that.

You seem to assume that this relationship is responsible for the breakup of his marriage. I don't know if that is true or not, but other, longer duration, things might well be in play here. People break up for lots of reasons. This relationship might have been the result, not the cause, of the breakup.

You seem to assume that this is an infrequent thing generally. But the history, generally, of people breaking marriage vows implies otherwise. "To death do us part" seems to be recognized in the breach. And students and professors actually falling in love when working closely or academic colleagues falling in love is fairly common. Not ideal, perhaps.

You seem to assume that he has promoted her only for his personal sexual satisfaction, not for her work. I think that is overreach. His job, actually, is to promote her, as it is to promote every other student.

You seem to assume that others are disadvantaged by this relationship, offering no proof. That may or may not be the case, but if not, then his professional behavior has been correct, independent of personal behavior. Generally speaking, people's personal relationships are their own business unless others are disadvantaged. Complain, if you must, about unfair behavior if you see it, but leave the personal things to the people involved.

Finally, I suggest that you examine your own motives for wanting to complain about this. Are you disappointed in some way that you haven't advanced as quickly as you thought you should?

I won't advise you whether to complain or not, actually, as I don't have all the necessary information, but think it through deeply before you act.

Comment: I will address your comments point by point.
1]This professor is known to be a predator. Both before and during his relationship with this girl he has approached with sexual intent several females and this is something a lot of his colleagues are aware of. 2] Obviously the fallout of his marriage is not this relationship with the particular girl but his lifelong philandering 3]I do not imply that this is infrequent. They seem to have a relationship and not a simple affair, albeit he is still approaching sexually other females in conferences

Comment: 4] Whether he promoted her because of her academic potential or not I do not know. I know the facts that say that after she left his lab for 2.5 year she didn't manage to create a single scientific output (not even a poster) in a very fast moving field. I normally have high expectations from students who are so stellar to deserve scholarships...

Comment: 5] Helping her to participate in a program with limited positions I think puts in disadvantage all other people who are interested and deserving to take these positions.  I understand that it is possible for professors and students to fall in love but at that point you just stop interact professionally at least while you are still at unequal academic levels. I expect that this professor will be for sure invited even as examiner for her PhD defense.

Comment: Also he is know to try to "promote" in one way or another all the females he is involved with to keep them coming back and probably to stop them from reporting him. This is not an isolated incident.

Comment: Academics who have personal interest or relations with a student should immediately remove themselves from any position of power related to this student (e.g. academic supervision). They should also not involve themselves in any discussions regarding the promotion, assessment or reward of said student. Recommending the student for promotion *is* an breach of integrity.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov Exactly!!! This is exactly my problem. I understand that you might fall in love or whatever but you cannot continue to influence her career

Comment: @ii.iiii If you contact a person responsible for Ethics in your University, they will explain you in details the exact processes / requirements of your organisation. Then you will know for sure whether or not what you witnessed seems like an breach of ethic code your organisation adheres to.

Comment: Given what you say here in comments it is extremely unlikely that his behavior is unknown to the people responsible for a correction.